# Regex - has delimiter get a substring, no delimiter get the whole string

Tags: regex, google-sheets

This is for Google Sheets so I am using REGEXEXTRACT that uses the RE2 flavor of regex.

I have two cases.

Case one, two strings with a delimiter. "**String One, String Two**".
In this case I want to extract what's before the delimiter.

Case two, just one string. "**String One**".
In this case, I want to extract the whole string.

I know it's possible to test the existence of the delimiter using a google sheets formula but I wonder if there is a possibility to do that just with a regex.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can simply use `SPLIT()` and `INDEX()` the result returning the very first element from the array.

Comment: agreed.  try this: replacing the comma with your real delimiter.
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A,",")),,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

Following the previous answers, I came out with the formula =IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),1),"")

Sometimes, regex is not the best solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### With Regex

You can use the regex expression `^[^,]*` to match a consecutive string of any characters except commas, starting at the beginning.

```
=regexextract(A1,"^[^,]*")
```

#### Split and Index

As others have noted, you can use the `=split()` formula to separate the input string by some delimiter. From there, you can use something like `index()` or `array_constrain()` to get the first element.

```
=index(split(A1,","),1,1)
```